# Difference between the Lorentz Transformed and Retarded Electric / Magnetic Fields

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

I can't understand the main difference between these 2 concepts. If we consider a particle moving at constant speed with electric field E' in the comoving frame, we can then deduce what we will observe in our frame using Lorentz Transformations.

On the other side, we have the Retarted electric field which describes what we observe when a charge is moving.

I think I am missing something because I cannot understand what is the difference between the two. Any help ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference is how you calculate them. In the case of the Lorentz transformed fields you calculate them in a frame where they are easy to calculate, and then Lorentz transform to the frame of interest. In the case of the retarded fields you work in a single frame and calculate the fields using the retarded time. Both methods should give the same answer.

Comment: Thank you this make sense! So using the retarded time is a way to account for relativistic effects when you observe an event that is alternative to the Lorentz Transform?

Comment: @bsaoptima sure, you could say it that way. I don’t think that I would say it that way because both are designed to calculate the fields and neither are worried about observations. I think there is a lot of unnecessary overemphasis on observers.